# Configurable Product - Disable and grey out out of stock

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

I've seen some posts about this but can't get to a conclusion.
In a configurable product with dropdown all option appears (in stock and out of stock), what I need is to disable the ones out of stock so the client can see they exist but cannot click them.
This because selecting and appearing below the price or adding to cart and then give the info that is out of stock does not sound good enough lacks visual information before you do a bunch of clicks makes lose time and we all know that customers don't like to lose time xD

So in summary, just need to disable all out of stock options and show something like "option name (out of stock)" in the dropdown.

Any good way to do this?

Thanks :D

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey, at the time I solved by adding this module https://github.com/Jitheesh/Magento2-configurable, then in the product page in theme I did some javascript that disabled all the options that had the text I added in that module. Later on I updates to 2.3.5-p1 and all worked fine by itself :D